# Subscription in Orion Context Broker Fiware

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

I try to send a subscription to my Orion Context Broker instance. I'm sending this JSON:

```
{
  "duration": "P1M",
  "reference": "http://130.206.127.23:1026/ngsi10/notifyContext",
  "notifyConditions": [
    {
      "condValues": [
        "PT10s"
      ],
      "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "1.0",
      "type": "Capsule",
      "isPattern": "false"
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [
    "temperature"
  ]
}
```

And I receive the next message:

```
<subscribeContextResponse>
  <subscribeError>
    <errorCode>
      <code>400</code>
      <reasonPhrase>Bad Request</reasonPhrase>
      <details>JSON Parse Error: <unspecified file>(1): invalid escape sequence</details>
    </errorCode>
  </subscribeError>
</subscribeContextResponse>
```

I put all attributes that it is using in [the documentation](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Context_subscriptions). But in the webinar [Orion Context Broker Webinar - Demo part 2](http://edu.fi-ware.org/mod/resource/view.php?id=219) I can see other attribute called `Throttling`, but I don't see in the documentation.

What I'm doing bad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with your request (copy-pasted) and this is the result (with Orion 0.17.0).

Command (you can check that the payload is exactly the one you used):

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "duration": "P1M",
  "reference": "http://130.206.127.23:1026/ngsi10/notifyContext",
  "notifyConditions": [
    {
      "condValues": [
        "PT10s"
      ],
      "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "1.0",
      "type": "Capsule",
      "isPattern": "false"
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [
    "temperature"
  ]
}
EOF
```

Result:

```
{
    "subscribeResponse": {
        "duration": "P1M", 
        "subscriptionId": "5489e0bfe5007d3271ab5a61"
    }
}
```

Thus, my test was ok so I tend to think that the problem is related with encoding and it is not shown in your question post, e.g. the usage of `“` (wrong) intead of `"` and things like that.

**EDIT:** another common source of problems is using script files containing the curl request to CB in "DOS text" (typically due to the usage of DOS/Windows text editors). This can be easility detected if you run `file yourfile.sh` and get the following

```
yourfile.sh: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

instead of the following

```
yourfile.sh: ASCII text
```

The solution is quite simple: transform the file to "Unix text", for example using the `dos2unix` command line tool.

Comment: I have asked the question about the subscription request problem. For the other question (i.e. What I need to put in the reference attribute? Do I need a program in execution in a server to receive the information about my subscription? Can I get a program from Orion Context Broker resources to do this task?) it is prefereable you create a new question in SOF, given that it is independent of the present one, please.

Comment: The problem is that I can't see where is the error with this response. I put the JSON code in jsoneditoronline.org and the document is well format. And I create the JSON in the same way that the rest of JSON to the other common operation of OCB :(

Comment: Maybe you can create a .sh to reproduce the problem, upload it to some public place (dropbox?) and pass me the URL, so I can try to reproduce the problem using it.

Comment: Ok, the problem is in the attribute "reference". I'm writing in Java this line:  cabecera.put("reference","http://130.206.127.23:1026/ngsi10/notifyContext");  And when I send the information, I'm sending http:\/\/130.206.127.23:1026\/ngsi10\/notifyContext

Comment: How I have to pass the URL? I'm trying with a String and I have this problem. Also with a URL object I have an error :(

Comment: I think this is quite general Java question that deserves a separated question in StackOverflow (or probably it has been already asked and answered).

Comment: Sure, but, I don't know what are the OCB expected in this attribute: a string? an URL, an int?

Comment: At JSON level, reference must be a string conforming to the URL format in the "http" or "https" protocol schemes (in the second case, you have to use an additiontal component as notification relayer, named Rush).

Comment: please, read the responses to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447101/write-correctly-an-url-in-json-with-java#27447101

Comment: I'm trying to do this manually like you inside my VM and I have the same error. Where I can see the log of ContextBroker?? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look to Logs section in the [Orion Installation & Administraiton manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subs‌​cribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Logs) and to the BROKER_LOG_DIR in /etc/sysconfig/contextBroker

Comment: I'm tryin at this moment with the example https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#ONCHANGE and I have the same error