# Attribute Reference for subscription in Orion Context Broker Fiware

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

What do I need to put in the reference attribute?

I'm using two forms, and the two are bad for `Orion Context Broker`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://130.206.127.23:1026/ngsi10/notifyContext");
//String url = "http://localhost:1028/accumulate";
cabecera.put("reference", ""+url);
```

With this code, I'm generating the next `JSON String` for the `reference` attribute

```
...."reference":"http:\/\/130.206.127.23:1026\/ngsi10\/notifyContext",...
```

And this is the response of `OCB`

```
<subscribeContextResponse>
  <subscribeError>
    <errorCode>
      <code>400</code>
      <reasonPhrase>Bad Request</reasonPhrase>
      <details>JSON Parse Error: <unspecified file>(1): invalid escape sequence</details>
    </errorCode>
  </subscribeError>
</subscribeContextResponse>
```

Also related to this parameter,do I need a program in execution in a server to receive the information about my subscription?
Can I get a program from Orion Context Broker resources to do this task?

The following is my JSON to call the service, but I'm not sure about the reference attribute. I want to send a subscription to my Orion Context Broker instance. I'm sending this JSON:

```
{
  "duration": "P1M",
  "reference": "http://130.206.127.23:1026/ngsi10/notifyContext",
  "notifyConditions": [
    {
      "condValues": [
        "PT10s"
      ],
      "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "1.0",
      "type": "Capsule",
      "isPattern": "false"
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [
    "temperature"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to keep questions focused in a single topic. In this sense, I'd suggest to rollback the editions to your question: in the first version you asked about the reference field (and that was ok), however in the new version you talk about a formating problem (already discussed in a different question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428114/subscription-in-orion-context-broker-fiware/27429885) thus introducting a new topic that can confuse the original purpose of the question and the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference element is described in [the Orion User Manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#ONTIMEINTERVAL):

> The callback URL to send notifications is defined with the reference
>   element.

Thus, if your reference is `http://130.206.127.23:1026/ngsi10/notifyContext` as shown in your example, you should have a REST server listening at host 130.206.127.23 port 1026, able to receive notifications in the `/ngsi10/notifyContext` path. Note that your CB (I mean, the one to which you are sending the subscribeContext request) is the actor that sends notification, not the actor that receives them, so it **must not** run at 130.206.127.23:1026.

You can implement the notifications receiver program in any programming language that you want (as long as it implements the required REST server interface). You can have a look to the [accumulator-server.py](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/accumulator-server.py), which is a "dummy" notification receiver example implemented in Python, used for testing.