# Write correctly an URL in JSON with Java

Tags: java, json, string, url

I need to write an attribute on a JSON document, and this attribute is an URL

This is my code:

```
String url = "http://localhost:1028/accumulate";
JSONObject cabecera = new JSONObject();
cabecera.put("reference", url);
```

But when I create the JSON,this attibute is writted in this way:

```
"reference":"http:\/\/localhost:1028\/accumulate",
```

So, the service that receives the JSON String, it's sending me an error:

```
<subscribeContextResponse>
  <subscribeError>
    <errorCode>
      <code>400</code>
      <reasonPhrase>Bad Request</reasonPhrase>
      <details>JSON Parse Error: <unspecified file>(1): invalid escape sequence</details>
    </errorCode>
  </subscribeError>
</subscribeContextResponse>
```

What is the correct way to write the URL??

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you _create the JSON_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when I create the JSON,this attibute is writted in this way:
>
> `"reference":"http:\/\/localhost:1028\/accumulate",`

That's fine, the backslashes are harmless, whatever you're using to serialize to JSON is just being a bit hyper with its escapes. The string represented by the above contains no backslashes at all, just slashes. `\/` inside a JSON string is exactly the same as `/`, as we can see from the highlighted rule from http://json.org:

[image]

("solidus" is a fancy term for slash)

Comment: Then, where is the problem in this attribute? If the service is waiting an string, and I send an string wellformed, is it possible that the problem is other in my JSON?

Comment: @jjmartinez there's nothing wrong with your JSON, the problem is that the code on the other end that is trying to parse it doesn't follow the JSON specification.

Comment: @jjmartinez: It's possible that whatever you're using to receive/validate/parse the JSON is broken and doesn't understand the escape sequence `\/`. If so, I'd switch to something that isn't broken. The sequence shows up as valid on both JSON.org and [in the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

Comment: I don't think the server (Orion Context Broker service) is broken. Please have a look to https://gist.github.com/fgalan/ecfe3af67007e414c6d6. Note that it uses the `\/`. If you run this script, it sends the request to the service and it is rightly processes, as shows this: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/75e86e441d328bc53158, corresponding to `db.csubs.find()` on the DB after request. Note the reference field at DB, which is rightly stored taking into account escaping. So, the problem have to be elsewhere (maybe the Java framework is doing some ugly related with encoding?)

Comment: @fgalan: It's always possible there's a problem with some other part of the JSON, or that you have a text encoding mismatch issue. But the JSON in the question is fine (assuming it's a fragment).